# Add x em to font size with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can wrtie JS code that sets the font size but I'd like to write a function that ADDS to the current font size. For example, it sets the font size to current size + 1em. Is it possible?

Comment: current size of which tag??

Comment: I'd like to increase the size of body tag with every click

Comment: Be more specific: e.g., I set responsive font sizes the way Bootstrap 4 does with RFS (cfr. https://github.com/twbs/rfs/tree/v8.0.4), but I don’t know if it’s your case here.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Get the current size with [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), the rest should be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `1em` which is a relative value is not trivial depending on what unit the font size of the element is currently based on.

What you could do is to use the current font size and use `calc` to add 1em, but if the original font size was relative then this will not have the expected result if the font size the relative one based on changes.

```js
function add1em() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(text, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  text.style.fontSize = 'calc(' + fontSize + ' + 1em)';
}


var text = document.getElementById("add1em").addEventListener('click', add1em, null, false);
```

```html
<p id="text">Some Text.</p>
<button id="add1em">add 1 em</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to fetch the current size:

```js
 function makeFontBigger(){
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(text, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  var fontSize = parseFloat(style); 
  text.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 1) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<p id="text">This is a nice example.<p>
<button onClick="makeFontBigger()">Make the font bigger!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current font-size of the text you want to update, add 10 (or however much you want) and then set it as the new font-size.

```js
function increaseFont() {
  var pTag = document.querySelector(".text");
  var newFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(pTag).getPropertyValue('font-size')) + 10;
  pTag.style.fontSize = newFont.toString(10) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Text<p>

<button onclick="increaseFont()">Increase Font</button>
```